# Migrate data from Develpment DB to Production DB with Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm kind newbie on Rails. I developed an small CMS running on Heroku and using Postgres.

I manually inserted a few data on my Development db. And I'd like to fill the Production DB with such data.

Both DB are equals. Same  structure, fields etc.

I tried through gem install yaml_db
 --> gem 'yaml_db' ->rake db:data:dump →  rake db:data:load

But I got: “rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:data:load'
”

Is that the proper approach? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are these constants that you're looking to have in your database or "fake" data?

Answer (score 0):

You can import your local database to heroku database easily using heroku pgbackups by follow the [instructions here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import).

Comment: PG backup are not avaliable now for new users, it become a part of Database add-ons itself and has totally different commands.

Answer (score 0):

Please check here in [Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

```
heroku db:push
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. I was able to dump and restore on my local db. But every time that I tried to restore the db at Heroku I got a error: pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header. And the only way to make the DB back to work (empity) is via heroku run rake db:reset. Any light?